# Excel: How to create filtered list using formula by criteria containing asterisks

Tags: excel, filtered-index

I will be very glad for your help. Here is my situation:

[image: My screenshot]

I know how to create such a filtered list using the array formula combining INDEX and SMALL functions but this does not allow me to use criteria containing asterisks. If I used criteria "1,2,3,4,5,6" instead of "1,*,*,*,5,6" I could simply use this:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=$F$3;ROW($A$1:$A$8)),ROW(1:1))),"")`

So my question is:

How to change this formula or which formula to use if I need to have criteria which includes asterisks as wildcard characters. I know IF function does not allow wildcard characters, so is there any workaround. Thanks.

Comment: typically, wildcard asterisks functionality is replaced with something like `isnumber(search(...))`

Comment: Thank you. I finally found a solution :-)